# syntaxhighlighter on blogger: the platform closes tags that it thinks are HTML? How can I fix that?

Tags: blogger, syntaxhighlighter

you can see tha in my blog: http://newbufferedwriter.blogspot.com/2012/03/risolutore-solitario-klondike-codice.html , blogger thinks that all #include directives from the standard library (so with the "<>" tags) are HTML tags, and in every snippet it close with an ugly "/string"  or "/iostream" (even stackoverflow recognize these like tags LOL...I put out the "<" and ">"). I tried with the CDATA section, but blogger sats me the he found an unknown tag...it's mad!

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance
Alberto

Answer (score 1):

Use `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` in your includes

Replace `#include <iostream>` with `#include &lt;iostream&gt;`